# How to clear radio selection in Foxit PDF reader?

Tags: pdf, foxit-reader

I've selected a box on a Foxit PDF form that I would like to clear because it was part of an conditional section on which I shouldn't have selected anything.

I tried pressing all the obvious buttons and have looked through the menus. I also found a promising article stating that I should go to the Forms menu where I could find a way to edit the controls, however the only option I had there was to reset the entire form which I don't really want to do.

Is there any way to clear a radio selection in Foxit (without having to select another radio option; obviously)?